# dumb-init and ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am developing ASP.NET 5 applications and running them inside containers. The executable produced by the build process is the one I execute when the container is started.

Recently I became aware of dumb-init, which is an init process for containers. It is possible to find it here: https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init

My question is: do I need it for .NET 5 applications? Or the runtime already handles the signals correctly?

Thanks for any help.